# How to limit returned product categories with thumbnails (WooCommerce)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories

My goal here is to show only child categories under category ID 93 (vendors) with a thumbnail and URL so people can click on the vendor logo and see other products in that category. I have everything mostly working, but I'm not sure how to limit my request to show only one child from my parent. This is admittedly very amateur - I am not a backend developer nor do I really understand how to write PHP.

```
<?php
echo $wp_query;

$terms_post = get_the_terms($product->ID, 'product_cat');

foreach ($terms_post as $term_cat) { 
    $term_cat_id = $term_cat->term_id;
    $category_url = get_term_link( $term_cat_id, 'product_cat', true );
    $thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta($term_cat_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
    $image_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id );
    echo '<a href="'. $category_url .'"><img src="' . $image_url . '" alt="" width="50" height="50"></a>'; 
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To show only 1 child from the parent, just use array_slice().

```
foreach(array_slice($terms_post, 0, 1) as $term_cat ) { 
    $term_cat_id = $term_cat->term_id;
    $category_url = get_term_link( $term_cat_id, 'product_cat', true );
    $thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta($term_cat_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
    $image_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id );
    echo '<a href="'. $category_url .'"><img src="' . $image_url . '" alt="" width="50" height="50"></a>'; 
}
```

Do let me know if it works.

**EDITED:**

Use the below code to get child categories using a parent category slug.

```
<?php
global $post;
$category_id = get_term_by('slug', 'PARENT-CAT-SLUG', 'product_cat');

$terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'product_cat');
foreach ($terms as $term) {
    if($term->parent === $category_id->term_id) { ?>
       <span class="product-sub-cats"><?php echo $term->name; ?></span>
      <?php  break;
    }
}
 ?>
```

Replace "PARENT-CAT-SLUG" with the slug of your Parent Category.

Comment: Rajeev, this is amazing. It almost does the job, but I only want to show child categories from category 93 (vendors). It will only show 1 thumbnail as there's only one brand applied - so if my product is a widget by Widget Maker, I want to show their logo below the rest of the meta. Does that make more sense?

Comment: This is working perfectly, I just need to add the thumbnail and link back in. I think I can manage that, but we'll see :)

 <?php global $post;
  $category_id = get_term_by('slug', 'vendors', 'product_cat');
  $terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'product_cat');
  foreach ($terms as $term) {
    if($term->parent === $category_id->term_id) { ?>
       <span class="product-sub-cats"><?php echo $term->name; ?></span>
      <?php break;
   }
  }
    ?>

Comment: Glad that I could help you.